# How to implement translations in design template package CSV's? How does echo $this->__('Text') work?

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, multistore, localisation

I have a design package setup like so:

`design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/locale/`

under which I have

`de_DE`, `en_GB` etc, under which I have corresponding `translate.csv` files with the various strings: `"Key", "Translation"`

I am trying to implement various strings in my theme using `echo $this->__('Text')`

However, it doesn't seem to work (I only see the string inside the `('Text')` displayed). I think I am missing some fundamental understanding of when Magento pulls strings from the CSV to be translated. Can someone please explain how to get these csv files to work?

Comment: What version of Magento are you running?

Comment: I am using Magento v: 1.7.0.2

Comment: Are you calling this outside of a normal magento template file? Maybe you need to call the helper class and make it something like <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->__('Text'); ?>

Also try enabling "Translate Inline" on Frontend in System>Configuration>Developer

Answer (score 84, accepted):

## TL;DR

If you are not interested in the details how the translation works, skip the content up to the
**What to check if your translation isn't working** section below, especially the subsection
**Solution for Module Scope Translation conflicts**.

## Magento Translation Overview

Magento prioritizes translations sources (from highest to lowest):

1. DB (the `core_translate` table)
2. The theme `translate.csv` file
3. The `app/locale/*/*.csv` files

## How is the translation array built?

### Module Translations

First all files from `app/locale/*/*.csv` that are referenced from active modules `etc/config.xml` files are parsed. Here is a walkthrough of the process:
Assume Magento finds the following `config.xml` section:

```
<!-- excerpt from Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml -->
<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Mage_Catalog>
                <files>
                    <default>Mage_Catalog.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Mage_Catalog>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
```

And in that file, the following translation is specified for the locale configured for the current store view:

```
"AAA","BBB"
```

Under these circumstances, Magento creates the following records in the translation array:

```
array(
    "AAA" => "BBB",
    "Mage_Catalog::AAA" => "BBB"
)
```

The second value is the *Module Scope Translation*. The prefixed module name is taken from the config XML node containing the translation file declaration.

If the same translation is specified again by a **second module file**, e.g. in `Some_Module.csv` the translation is `"AAA","CCC"`, it will **NOT OVERWRITE** the `"AAA"` setting. Instead, it will only add a new record with the second module name `"Some_Module::AAA" => "CCC"`.

If the developer mode is enabled, it will even **unset** the `"AAA"` record if it finds a second record with the same key in another module translation. This makes it easier to spot module translation conflicts during development.

### Theme Translations

Second, the translations loaded from the first `translate.csv` file in the theme fallback for the current locale simply replace existing records in the translation array.
So continuing the previous example, a `translate.csv` record `"AAA","DDD"` would lead to the following translation data:

```
array(
    "AAA" => "DDD", // This is overwritten by the translate.csv file
    "Mage_Catalog::AAA" => "BBB",
    "Some_Module::AAA" => "CCC"
)
```

Of course records in the `translate.csv` with new translation keys are simply added to the array.

### Database Translations

Translations from the `core_translate` table are basically merged into the translation array just like the theme translations.
Existing keys from the module or theme translations are overwritten by database records, new ones are added.

## Translation Lookup

When the `__()` method is called, Magento first looks for a translation in array matching the current module.
The current module is determined by the class name on which the `__()` class is called.   For example, in blocks the responsible method looks like this:

```
// Excerpt from Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
public function getModuleName()
{
    $module = $this->getData('module_name');
    if (is_null($module)) {
        $class = get_class($this);
        $module = substr($class, 0, strpos($class, '_Block'));
        $this->setData('module_name', $module);
    }
    return $module;
}
```

The methods in Helpers and Controllers work correspondingly.

### Example Lookup Scenarios

For an example, lets say `$this->__('AAA')` is called in a template file.
If the associated block has the type `Mage_Core_Block_Template`, Magento will first check for a `Mage_Core::AAA` record. If it doesn't find it, it will fall back to the translation for the key `AAA`.
In the example scenario this will result in the translation `DDD` (from the `translate.csv` file).

In a different scenario the associated block could be `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`. In this case Magento would first check for a translation record `Mage_Catalog::AAA`, and would find the translation `AAA`.

So in effect, the module scope translations have a higher priority then any *generic* translations.
Which translation is used depends on which module the class is from calling the `__()` method.

## What to check if your translation isn't working

If your translation from a `translate.csv` file isn't being used, follow this checklist:

1. Is the translation cache turned off/refreshed?  (Solution: clear the cache)
2. Is the `translate.csv` file really in the theme fallback for the current store?  (Solution: fix theme configuration)
3. Is there a conflicting record for the translation in the `core_translate` table?  (Solution: remove the conflicting record from `core_translate`)
4. If all the previous points aren't the cause, there must be a conflicting translation from a different module.  (Solution: see below)

### Solution for Module Scope Translation conflicts

If you find the final case is true, simply add the translation a second time to your `translate.csv` **with** the module scope of the module doing the translation.
In the example, if you always wanted `AAA` to be translated as `DDD`via the theme translation, you could do this in your `translate.csv`:

```
"AAA","DDD"
"Mage_Catalog::AAA","DDD"
"Some_Module::AAA","DDD"
```

In practice, I only add the module scope to the translation if there is a conflict, that is, if a translation isn't working.

## Additional Notes

### Inline Translation

The inline translation feature of Magento also adds the custom translations to the `core_translate` table using the module scope prefix.

### Backward Compatibility

The priority of the theme translations used to be higher then the database translations up to Magento version 1.3 or so.

### XML Translation

Magento sometimes evaluate `translate=""`arguments in `config.xml`, `system.xml` and layout XML to translate child node values.
A helper class can be specified in those cases using the `module=""` argument to specify the module for the translation scope.
If no `module` argument is specified in the XML, the `core/data` helper is used to translate the child node values.

### Further Information

I confess I glossed over some details of the Magento translation process in this post, but only because I don't want to too much information.

- Some technical details while the translation array is built
- The possibility to use additional translation files for modules
- Store view scope for `core_translate` records
- Pros and cons using the different methods of translation

Please ask a separate question if more information is required.

Comment: OK, I am incredibly sorry everyone, but someone else turned on the caches without telling me... Probably the moment I started working on the translations. Sigh. This information was incredibly helpful for my understanding of the translation process in Magento though. Many many thanks, this definitely answers all the questions I had about how the `__()` function works.

Comment: A pretty good overview of Magento's translation architecture can also be found here: https://gist.github.com/antonmakarenko/7538216

Comment: @Vinai, excellent answer. It really helped me to solve an translation issue I posted a question on [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/42154/6549).  Surprisingly Mage_Tax was conflicting with my theme's translations which seems contrary to how Magento is meant to prioritize translations

Answer (score 14):

### Translation Sources

Translations are merged from different sources: **Module translations** from the respective XML files, **theme translations** from the `translate.csv` of the current theme, and **inline translations** from the database.

Translations can be strictly module specific (only valid within a module), that’s always the case for inline translations and optionally for theme translations. To achieve this, you have to define them with module prefix in the translate.csv:

```
"Mage_Catalog::Add to cart","In die Einkaufstüte legen"
```

Translations from modules (like `Mage_Catalog.csv`) are only strictly module specific, if the DEVELOPER MODE is on. Otherwise the translation fom the first loaded module is used globally for all modules that do not have their own translation for the text.

I assembled a flow chart that shows how each text from the different sources is merged in the translation array:

[image: Translation Merge]
<sup>`data` is the translation array</sup>

#### Evil Edge Case

If the translated string is equal to the untranslated string, the translation is ignored. That sounds like useful optimization at first glance, but this way you cannot easily translate a string unchanged in one module and changed in another module, because the changed translation will be the only one and become global.

### Translation Lookup

For which module the translation is looked up, depends on the module of the class, on which the method `__()` has been called. Then, the lookup in the translation array is as follows:

[image: Translation Lookup]
<sup>`data` is the translation array</sup>

### Scope Definition

There are possibilities to change the module for one class, which is especially useful for blocks and helpers. Best practice is to always set the module name explicitly when rewriting a core class. How it works, varies between Helpers, Blocks and Contollers (as of Magento CE 1.9.1)

#### Example For A Block:

```
class IntegerNet_AwesomeModule_Block_Catalog_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product
{
    public function getModuleName()
    {
        return 'Mage_Catalog';
    }
}
```

For blocks, you also can set the `module_name` parameter in layout XML:

```
<block type="integernet_awesomemodule/catalog_product" name="test" module_name="Mage_Catalog" />
```

#### Example For A Helper:

```
class IntegerNet_AwesomeModule_Helper_Catalog extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data
{
    protected $_moduleName = 'Mage_Catalog';
}
```

For frontend controllers, you can set the property `_realModuleName`, for admin controllers, `_usedModuleName` (yay for consistency)

### Other Translation Methods

In XML files (config.xml, system.xml, layout) you can specify if nodes should be translated with the `translate` attribute. You should also add the `module` attribute to specify the scope, but here the value has to be the **helper alias**, not the module name as above.

```
<one_column module="page" translate="label">
    <label>1 column</label>
    <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
    <layout_handle>page_one_column</layout_handle>
    <is_default>1</is_default>
</one_column>
```

In JavaScript you can use the `Translator` object that is globally available:

```
Translator.translate('Please wait, loading...');
```

but you have to make the translations that you want to use in JavaScript available to the translator object. This is done through `jstranslator.xml` files in the `etc` directories of modules.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jstranslator>
    <loading translate="message" module="core">
        <message>Please wait, loading...</message>
    </loading>
</jstranslator>
```

`loading` can be any string but must be globally unique. The `translate` and `module` attributes are used as in other XML files. The value of `message` and its translation is added to the JS Translator object.

### Troubleshooting

Even if you know all the complicated rules, it's sometimes hard to see why some translation is working as it is (or not working). To make this easier, I developed a "Translation Hints" module which shows where translations are coming from:

> Get it here: https://github.com/schmengler/TranslationHints
>
> Screenshot: [image: Translation Hints]

---

Based on my blog posts and slides on the topic:

- http://www.integer-net.de/praesentation-uebersetzungen-in-magento/
- http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2015/02/translationhints-0-2-for-magento-published/

Comment: I hope I'm not spamming by mentioning that my free Yireo EmailOverride module will allow custom CSV module files to be placed in the theme as well. Not just translate.csv.

Answer (score 6):

Have you cleared your cache?

Is your system set to the locale of the file you're testing?

Can Magento find the file it's looking for when it loads the theme translation (some temporary `var_dump`;exit; statements should help.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php
protected function _loadThemeTranslation($forceReload = false)
{
    $file = Mage::getDesign()->getLocaleFileName('translate.csv');
    $this->_addData($this->_getFileData($file), false, $forceReload);
    return $this;
}
```

Can the `_getTranslatedString` method find what it's looking for in the data array?

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php
protected function _getTranslatedString($text, $code)
{
    $translated = '';
    if (array_key_exists($code, $this->getData())) {
        $translated = $this->_data[$code];
    }
    elseif (array_key_exists($text, $this->getData())) {
        $translated = $this->_data[$text];
    }
    else {
        $translated = $text;
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

Comment: None of the caches are active, I'm not sure if my system is set to the locale, but translations work in certain template files accordingly (by changing the shop). For example, a string in my `translate.csv` translates properly in `/app/design/frontend/package_name/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` but not in `/app/design/frontend/package_name/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml`

Comment: You were right, someone turned on the cache without telling me. Oops, my apologies and thank you for the information!

Comment: @waffl No need to apologize — I think every Magento developer does that at least once a week.