# Is it possible to override Magento theme files?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, overrides, parent-child-theme

I previously asked a question regarding overriding Magento core files and learned that I can copy files to local folder and the core files will be overridden. Is this also possible for Themes? I want to modify Magento theme files, but those changes will be lost whenever a new theme update will be rolled out. I will have to do all those changes again.

Is is possible to override Theme files as we do with core files? If yes, please point me to the right direction.

I thought it would be possible by copying this to local folder, but confused about the location/path to follow while copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit theme files same way as code
just copy your current theme in the new folder and assign it in the backed at

`system->config->general->design->themes` .

and set your folder name in the templates and Default field.
also create new folder in skin folder for css and js.

simply same way you make a new them structure as your current theme just name of your theme is changed.
just copy your theme folder in

`app\design\frontend\default\currunt-theme` to

`app\design\frontend\default\new-theme`

all files in it are remain same
then go to

`skin\frontend\default\currunt-theme` to

`skin\frontend\default\new-theme`

and then assign it in the back-end  in

`system->config->general->design->themes`

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating a new theme.  Note the base theme is a folder called `app/design/frontend/default/base/`.  Let's pretend your theme is "tony" and create a folder called `app/design/frontend/default/tony/`.  Now go to the Magento admin, click on the menu System > Configuration, then click on Design.  Fill the page in like this before saving.

[image]

Your new theme is now active but looks exactly like the base theme.  Copy the file `app/design/frontend/default/base/customer/account/navigation.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/default/tony/customer/account/navigation.phtml`.  Make some edits to the new file and look again at your site, it should have changed!

If not go to the admin menu System > Cache Management and turn off all caches until you have finished working on the site.

[See more here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8928/changing-default-values/8957#8957)

Comment: What will be the behavior after doing this? Will the changes to the theme (after updates) reflect in the copied theme? What I want to know is, will it work as a child theme or an independent theme?

Comment: You will not loose anything that's why we are using our theme.

Comment: So, only the files that need to be modified are required to be copied. Is it? Not sure if I really understood the concept.

Comment: Yes, just copy required template and modify it in your theme

Comment: Please read here for more detail http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-a-new-magento-theme/ if it's help you then you may accept this answer

Comment: The link provided is very helpful. I am modifying template and css files in the theme. So, I need to specify the package name, templates folder and Skin folder in the Settings. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I just got confused with the screenshots, the one you provided and the one shown in the reference article.