# Magento 1.6.0 footer.phtml translation

Tags: magento-1.6, footer

I'm using magento 1.6.0 with multi language (English and Russian).
in my modified theme , there are some phrases that I want to translate (**about us**, **my account** .. etc). 
I understood that the language is reading from a file (csv files). 
In which csv file do I need to add my new phrases for the footer page?

Thanks 
Guy

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest for you the best option would be to add translations under your theme, I assume your site has a theme and is not using the default theme.

What you will need to do is under your theme create a locale folder. Then a folder for your language `de_DE` or maybe `ru_RU` for Russian, I am not sure. Then under each language folder create a translate.csv. This file will contain all the original phrases and the desired translations.

For more information on translations I suggest reading:

1. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6725/158
2. http://tomrobertshaw.net/2010/03/magento-themes-using-locales-with-translate-csv/

Comment: Hi ) thanks for your fast reply and support . inside theme folder (../app/design/fronted/default/mytheme/) I made a new directory that call "locale" and under it I made sub directory call "en_US" . I put the translate.csv file with this line : "aboutus","about us" . and at the footer.phtml file I add this line : <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('aboutus') ?>         but, I don't see the translation .

Comment: To translate you should do something like `echo $this->__('aboutus');`

Comment: but im getting this line " echo $this->__('aboutus'); " and not "About us"