# Italian translation.csv for tax not working

Tags: magento-1.9, template, localisation, onestepcheckout, conflict

We have a Italian website on our Magento installation.  All the translations are working from our theme's **locale/it_IT/translate.csv** file with the exception of `"Tax","IVA"`.  On the italian site *Tax* is being translated to *Tasse*  which is the default Magento translation that seems to be coming from **app/locale/it_IT/**.

I've reviewed this excellent [Magento Stackexchange answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6725/6549) on this topic but can't seem to get it to work.

The translation is not working on our checkout page or to be more specific our **/it/onestepcheckout/index/** page.

I thought that maybe our translation was conflicting with another module, I'm not sure how to check which module it could be conflicting with, so I guessed it was a checkout module and updated my csv with:

```
"Tax","IVA"
"Mage_Checkout::Tax","IVA"
"Magestore_Onestepcheckout::Tax","IVA"
```

I also tried to check to see where the 'tax' string was being called from to check that it was being called throught the `__()` method but couldn't find it in a template.  The closest I came was in the **/onestepcheckout/onestepcheckout/review/totals.phtml** template which has a method `<?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer', $_colspan); ?>`.  Here is the template file in it's entirety:

```
<?php
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2010 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php if ($this->getTotals()): ?>
<tfoot>
    <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <?php $_colspan = $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 3 : 2; ?>
    <?php echo $this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan); ?>
    <?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer', $_colspan); ?>
    <?php if ($this->needDisplayBaseGrandtotal()):?>
    <tr>        
        <td class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $_colspan; ?>">
            <small><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Your credit card will be charged for') ?></small>
        </td>
        <td class="a-right">
            <small><?php echo $this->displayBaseGrandtotal() ?></small>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif?>
    <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</tfoot>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I also checked the `core_translate` table and it was empty, I made sure the cache was cleared and disabled.  All the other translations from our theme's **locale/it_IT/translate.csv** file are working.

Any help or suggestions of where I should look would be really appreciated.  Could I add the translation from the `core_translate` table

Comment: Have you tried turning inline translations on? it's in `system/configuration/advanced/developer`?

Comment: yes, but I can't get it working on that part of the page.  The totals are loaded with Ajax by the OneStepCheckout and when I have inline translations on they do not load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the issue, the core Mage_Tax module was conflicting my theme's translation.csv, I was able to overcome it by simply adding the below to my theme's **locale/it_IT/translate.csv**

```
"Tax","IVA"
"Mage_Tax::Tax","IVA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check in "Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones & Rates" ?

Here you can find your taxes title for each store view

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work, thanks :(