# Translation Checkout/Cart RWD Package

Tags: checkout, cart

I am new to Magento and setuped a shop on my local appache with the Magento_de install package. Everything worked fine for me excepting a few translation issues. I choosed the RWD package. Some I could fix by myself but I got a problem on the checkout page. Under the items in the cartlist there is a td with cart-footer-actions class. Inside this td you can find a link to clear the cart, a link to update the cart and a further one to shop on. In which template file I can find this markup?

Thanks for any responses

MOE

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't make translations directly in the template files. You should use Magento's translation files to translate to your language. You can find those files in

```
app/locale/yourlanguage_YOURLANGUAGE/
```

If your language isn't there, you probably can find your language pack somewhere on the internet (in Magento 1.9.0.1 a lot of languages were included). Translations are also available on [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-experience/internationalization-localization.html?utm_source=mc&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=translations).

As for the links you are trying to translate, a logical translation file to look for is `Mage_Checkout.csv`.

Don't forget to edit those translation files with an editor that can save in UTF-8 encoding. I always use Wordpad for this task.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know about the locale directory but some parts doesn't work or are hard coded in the template. For example the 'VIEW ALL' in the category navigation was hard coded to the template and I had to change it there. So could you please tell me where to find the mentioned parts?

Comment: You should be able to find those parts in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml`. I have checked this for my installation (CE 1.9.1.0) and this file contains the `__()` method for `Update Shopping Cart`, `Empty Cart` and `Continue Shopping`. So translation should work, unless something else is wrong. Have you disabled/cleared all cache?

Comment: Yes I found it in the template file you mentioned and so I was able to replace the English -or- with an German -oder- :) I cleared the Cache and added Empty Cart also to the translate.csv in rwd/default/locale/de_DE but it still doesn't work. Any other idea why this failed?

Comment: If you want to use custom translation files in your package/theme then I think you need to specify this in `System > Configuration > General > Design > Themes > Translations`. But there could be other reasons as well, like a conflicting record in the `core_translate` table of your database or conflicting translation of another module. Please check out Vinai's answer to [this question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t), it's very informative.

Comment: Thank you for the great link. Adding the entry to the core_translate table worked :)