# Password reset messages are all in English

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

The shop I'm working on has 3 store views with different languages: en_US, de_DE, and fr_FR.
When I click on the link for "Forgot your Password or want a new one?", and enter the email, I always get the message in English:

"If there is an account associated with youremail@yourshop.com you will receive an email with a link to reset your password."

In the locale csv files, the translations exist, and I've checked the keys (string before the comma), compared them with the keys used in the codes, they seem to equal.

The same problem is with other messages in the process.
Maybe the storeId value is wrong when the message will be created...

Answer (score 1):

**Turn off developer mode.** Developer mode is either turned on in `index.php` with `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` or with an environment variable `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE`, for example in the `.htaccess` file.

#### Explanation

The controller uses the `customer` helper to translate the strings, but they are defined only in `Mage_Adminhtml.csv`, so it should be the `adminhtml` helper. Translation scope is more strict in developer mode so that you can detect possible conflicts before they occur. With developer mode turned off, the translation falls back to any translation from another module if there is no translation in the current module.

More info on the translation system: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78483/243