# Per-Module Translations

Tags: inline-translations

I've seen many examples [like this one](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-translating-strings-from-specific-modules/) about how to do per-module translations. It looks like this:

```
"Product Name","Items in Your Cart"
```

becomes

```
"Mage_Checkout::Product Name","Items in Your Cart"
```

However, in all of the versions of Magento I've tried it on, (1.7.0.0,  1.9.1.0 and 1.14.0.0) this doesn't work.

Is this for an outdated version of Magento, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably only ever use module prefixes whenever there are conflicts between translations, and only in `translate.csv`. Also, when developer mode is enabled and there is a conflict, the string is not translated at all.

For more information, see the [excellent exposition on Magento translations](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t/6725#6725) by [Vinai](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/766/vinai).

Comment: Nicely answered. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for the entertaining podcast!