# Rename "Sale" in "New products" slider

Tags: layout, product-list, store-view, localisation, slider

I have two store views in my shop, German and English.

In my English store view, my product slider shows products as "sale" (the pink eye-catcher):

[image: Screenshot]

And in the German store view it's shown as "Verkauf" but I want to change that, also to "Sale".

I use the language pack, maybe I must change the translation, but where?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Translations are stored in csv files under app/locale/store
Look for your specific store (german) and look for the page's specific csv.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you might have is, that Sale is a common word in magento, therefore you might want to change your template first to have a better name for it, so only this exact position is changed.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9, the *"Sale"* translation only occurs once, in `Mage_Paypal.csv` (*"Sales"* is used much more often).

You can take advantage from this fact and create a new translation specific to the `Mage_Catalog` module, which will be used in product lists (if this particular block is from a different module, change `Mage_Catalog` accordingly below).

To do so, create a theme translation file `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/locale/de_DE/translate.csv` (if it does not exist yet) and add the following line:

```
"Mage_Catalog::Sale","Sale "
```

**The trailing space is important!** Magento has a quirk in the translation system, that translations where the original string is equal to the translated string are completely ignored. This results in a fallback to the translation from `Mage_Paypal.csv` just as before. Adding a space (or a non printable character if you prefer) will make the string different and it will actually be used.

More on the topic: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78483/243

Answer (score 0):

Instead of change values at database table for magento inline translation – you can use default magento  GUI  interface for translation. To enable this feature you need login to the admin panel, then open System->Configuration->Developer tab. The next step will be selection of magento scope of configuration. It can be done by selecting store view at the left top dropdown.

See more detail here :- 
http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/enable-use-magento-inline-translation-video.html