# How do I edit the register form?

Tags: register

I want to change the Middlename/Initial text to the german translation in my register form. But where do I need to fix it? The only place where I found this text was in two core foulders.

[image]

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using magento `translation  process`,you can  do easily

Check how translation works:

1. [Translating Magento frontend works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495235/translating-magento-frontend)
2. [vinai Koop answer:](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t/6725#6725)
3. [belvg](http://blog.belvg.com/editing-magento-translate-csv-file.html)

For your case you can do this:

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/locale/Your Language Code/translate.csv
```

and this:

```
"Middlename/Initial text","Your Text In German"
```

add this file