# Magento Translation for coupon code not working

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

In `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` I see:

```
$this->_getSession()->addError(
    $this->__(
       'Coupon code "%s" is not valid.',
        Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode)
    )
);
```

In my theme's `translate.csv` I have added:

```
"Mage_Checkout::Coupon code ""%s"" was applied.","test"
"Coupon code ""%s"" is not valid.","test"
```

If I edit the controller code directly, it works. The translate.csv does not work -- it still outputs the original text, 'Coupon code "blah" is not valid.'.

I even tried editing the translation in `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv` but it didn't work either.

What have I missed? Shouldn't it be outputting "test" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure, you should add the translation scope (i.e. the module name) to both translations:

```
"Mage_Checkout::Coupon code ""%s"" was applied.","test"
"Mage_Checkout::Coupon code ""%s"" is not valid.","test"
```

Don't forget to clean the cache after changing translations.

Comment: It was the cache needing to be cleared! Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: By the way, it does not need the `Mage_Checkout::` scope for this particular translation.

Comment: Yes, as long as it is globally unique (see http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78483/243)