# Helper data not found in custom module

Tags: module, magento-1, helper

I am getting error: **Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Assel_Holidays_Helper_Data' not found**

Here is config.xml--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
        <Assel_Holidays>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Assel_Holidays>
   </modules>
   <admin>
        <routers>
            <holidays>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Assel_Holidays</module>
                    <frontName>holi</frontName>
                </args>
            </holidays>
        </routers>
   </admin>
   <frontend>
        <routers>
            <holidays>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Assel_Holidays</module>
                    <frontName>holidays</frontName>
                </args>
            </holidays>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
   <global>
      <helpers>
            <holidays>
                <class>Assel_Holidays_Helper</class>
            </holidays>
      </helpers>
      <blocks>
            <holidays>
                <class>Assel_Holidays_Block</class>
            </holidays> 
      </blocks>
   </global>
</config>
```

I have helper class in **Data.php** in **Assel/Holidays/Helper/** folder.

Here is the **Data.php**

```
<?php
class Assel_Holidays_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Here is the **app/etc/modules/Assel_Holidays.xml**--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Assel_Holidays>
          <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Assel_Holidays>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I couldn't found out what is the reason behind it.

Comment: DO You define Data.php at Assel/Holidays/Helper?

Comment: Please check my edits

Comment: Seems like you are calling your helper this way: `Mage::helper('assel_holidays')` instead of `Mage::helper('holidays')` check your code

Comment: I am not calling like this `Mage::helper('holidays')` anywhere

Comment: is your CodePoll correctly configured, look into app/etc/modules/Assel_Holidays.xml which codePool is configured there ?

Comment: @roman204 check my `Assel_Holidays.xml` added above.

Comment: your compilation enable or disable???

Answer (score 1):

> I am not calling like this Mage::helper('holidays') anywhere

Then you use it indirectly with translation of XML nodes. Please check your **system.xml** and/or **adminhtml.xml** files and replace `module="Assel_Holidays"` with `module="holidays"`

> In XML files (config.xml, system.xml, layout) you can specify if nodes
>   should be translated with the `translate` attribute. You should also
>   add the `module` attribute to specify the scope, but here the value
>   has to be the **helper alias**, not the module name as above.
>
> ```
> <one_column module="page" translate="label">
>     <label>1 column</label>
>     <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
>     <layout_handle>page_one_column</layout_handle>
>     <is_default>1</is_default>
> </one_column>
> ```

Learn more: [How to implement translations in design template package CSV's? How does echo $this->__('Text') work?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t/78483#78483)

Comment: nice explanation Fabian