# How to translate Magento validate.js error

Tags: localisation

I have a website with 2 stores (English and Spanish). Now I need to translate validation messages in Spanish. Like for example:

> Please enter a valid email address.

Please suggest how I can achieve this?

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751094/magento-translate-text-from-javascript-files#7751385)

Comment: basically all default messages are added in app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/jstranslator.xml

Comment: You need to add it's equivalent in translate csv file

Comment: To learn about translate.csv see also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t/78483#78483

Answer (score 0):

Just add the translation in you `app/locale/LOCALE-CODE/Mage_Newsletter.csv` file.