# How to translate extra custom strings in template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, helper, ce-1.9.2.4

**Magento Core**: 1.9.2.4
**Theme**: Milano - Fashion Responsive Magento Theme

I have added a few extra custom strings in `/app/design/frontend/alomilano/home02_fashion/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml`
like this:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('need help?') ?>
```

also tried like this:

```
<?php echo $this->__('need help?') ?>
```

and added the strings in `/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv` & `/app/locale/el_GR/Mage_Catalog.csv` like this:

`"need help?","need help?"` (en_US)
`"need help?","χρειάζεσαι βοήθεια;"` (el_GR)

The translation in Greek (el_GR) works perfect, but when I switch to the **English** website (en_US) it still shows me the Greek translation!

I have clear **ALL** caches (many times).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t

Answer (score 0):

Try to use inline translation.

Go to

> System > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer

Find section `Translate Inline` and Enable it (Frontend/Backend)

Then go to page that you want to translate and click on text that you want to translate.
Translate pop-up will open.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv` go to your `app/design/theme_vendor/theme_name/locale/en_US/translate.csv` and add your translations here.
Use the same for another language you have.

**Note:** `theme_vendor/theme_name` is alike `base/default` or `default/modern`