# Change Shipping label in cart and checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change shipping lable on cart and checkout page from **Delivery** to **Shipping** and I get file from it's coming but I can't find that from where it's coming to this file.

in shipping.phtml file I get below line from it's coming.

**`<?php echo $this->getExcludeTaxLabel() ?>`**

So where can I find it?

Comment: Please share screenshot if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow that reference through to the block class which is rendering the template, you end up at `Mage_Tax_Block_Checkout_Shipping`:

```
public function getExcludeTaxLabel()
{
    return $this->helper('tax')->__('Shipping Excl. Tax (%s)', $this->escapeHtml($this->getTotal()->getAddress()->getShippingDescription()));
}
```

What `$this->helper('tax')->__()` tells you is that the `Mage_Tax` module is responsible for translating the string **"Shipping Excl. Tax (%s)"**. (This would be important if there were multiple modules with this string but you only wanted to translate it when rendered by a certain module.) You can find this string as part of the translation CSV files under *`./app/locale/`*, e.g. *`./app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv`*. Searching all other translation files shows that this string is unique in the translations list, so you can effect a translation via a custom *`translate.csv`* file in your theme, or via inline translation in the admin. Everything you want to know about translations can be found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6725/5).

Comment: perfect!!! accepted