# Mage_Module_Helper_Data not found in Magento C.E 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module, configuration, xml, helper

I am using magento 1.9 C.E and I have this issue whenever I try to disable any module from **`app/etc/modules/Mymodule_Custom.xml`**

```
    <active>false</false>
```

It throws the error **Mage_Module_Helper_Data not found**. I don't understand why it is coming and this is the problem with almost all the extensions that I'm using. Please help me out folks.

Comment: Can you give me the exact error. Bcoz I have face the same issue in past I can Help you in that

Comment: Maybe your helper class is getting called from some other module, check the stack trace of error in exception.log

Comment: I have used a few extensions of this vendor and whenever, I'm trying to perform the activity of disabling the error is thrown.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Price_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/eleczo/trunk/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: The helper is probably still used by translations in XML. Search the XML files for `module="mymodule_custom"`. Also, did you clear the cache?

Comment: I am not using this helper anywhere else. The helper is not being used as there is nothing written inside the helper code, it is only written to avoid error.

Comment: The empty helper has a purpose: load module specific translations. That's why I suspected the reason to be translated strings in the XML. See also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t/78483#78483 (**Other Translation Methods**)

Comment: which theme are you using??

Comment: I am using rwd/default.

Comment: do you know last extension that you installed after that this error is coming

Comment: The problem is not with just this particular extension, it is problem with all the extensions of this vendor, and a couple of more extensions. I haven't installed any extensions recently in like 9 months or so.

Comment: ok if you think that this particular supplier extension has issue then provide me config.xml and adminhtml.xml any one so we have better idea

Comment: @Murtuza Please provide your email id, I'll send it to you, I can't put it here just like this.

Comment: murtuzazabuawala@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45084/discussion-between-abhishek-dhanraj-shahdeo-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: I have shared the code in the chatroom, please review it.

Comment: Do you have any modules installed that their name contain the word "Price" (for example Tralala_Price.xml) ?

Comment: Try to 
clear the entry for that module from the DB table 'core_resources' and 'core_config_data';

Comment: Try to:
1. Remove data related to that module from 'core_resource' & 'core_config_data';
2. Then remove the module and clear cache from command line;
3. Also note, if that extension provider provides any basic necessary extension for all other extensions from that team. If so, make note you have that

Answer (score 4):

### The error

The error comes from the fact that the helper class of the module you're disabling is being used somewhere else in the code. For example, it could be:

- In another module
- In the templates

### Find the file using it

So first, you need to find out what is the name of the helper.

To do so, open `app/code/<codePool>/Mymodule/Custom/etc/config.xml` and look for the following piece of code:

```
<helpers>
    <module>
        <class>Mymodule_Custom_Helper</class>
    </module>
</helpers>
```

Here you have to take note the name of the node between `<helpers>` and `<class>`. In my example, it is **module**

Now, you need to find out where this helper name is being used.

To do so, you can **use the following command on your Magento root folder**:

```
grep -r "module" . | grep -v "app/code/<codePool>/Mymodule/Custom"
```

This command basically means:

> Look for the string **module** in my Magento folder but exclude the result from `app/code/<codePool>/Mymodule/Custom`

Thanks to this command you should be able to find where your helper is being used outside of your module quickly.

**Notice**: the command above will not exclude the templates or layout files from the module. Thus if your helper is being used in the module templates/layouts those files will be displayed in the list. To avoid that you can add extra grep to the command for instance:

```
grep -r "module" . | grep -v "app/code/<codePool>/Mymodule/Custom" | grep -v "app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule/custom"
```

### Once you found the code

Once you've found the code, I can't tell you what to do as it's a case by case decision. If you're disabling the module, you should definitely remove that helper call and/or refactor the file where it's being used.

Comment: I am not using the helper anywhere, not in that module or any other module or any phtml file.

Comment: Also, when I am removing the complete module that is deleting the module, it is throwing the same error.

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo yeah it is because your helper is definitely used somewhere. Give a try to my procedure

Comment: I have checked the whole project, the helper is being used only in that module, when I'm completely deleting the whole code of that module, it is throwing the same error.

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo maybe you have compilation enabled ? Check under System > Tools > Compilation and disable it, recompile then reenable it.

Comment: No, compilation has not been sed, and it is disabled too.

Comment: Seems if you have deleted the whole modules code then either that particular helper is getting used somewhere else or its cache.